# How to hide a Panel, in Visual Basic 2013 ASP.NET, so it doesn't leave a big gap on the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two panels, one below the other. The 1st panel is visible and the 2nd panel is not visible. When user presses a button, I need the 1st panel to disappear, to be replaced by the 2nd panel.

But when the 1st panel becomes invisible and 2nd becomes visible, the page has a big gap where the 1st panel was.

Here is how I hide the first panel:

```
Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    START_SECTION_PANEL.Visible = False
    CONTACT_INFO_PANEL.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I tried `display none` but it still shows the spaces:

```
    Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    START_SECTION_PANEL.Visible = False
    START_SECTION_PANEL.Style.Add("display", "none")

    CONTACT_INFO_PANEL.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: use dispaly:none css see more on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: How are you hiding the panel?  What resulting markup/styling is causing that space?

Comment: Yes, show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

```
Panel1.Visible = false;
```

Should do the trick. 
Check if you have some styles like **margin** for 2nd panel.

Or you can add styles like:

```
display: none;
```

and change CssClass onclick

Comment: "display: none" is what I want, but no effect:  still shows space gap.

Comment: Don't you have some css that doesn't allow your panel to get closer?